# Searching within Python list

Tags: python, list, search, find

I am struggling with the identification of specific items in a Python list.
The list contains of 14 foldernames within my directory (dir). These can be separated by filtering for a combination of three letters (e.g. 'UPB') within the folder's name. I need the name of the folder to start a process with that string.

Therefore I tried this code:

```
[a for a in dir if a != "*UPB*"]
```

This should give me all the list elements from 'dir' which contain the string "*UPB*", right? However, it doesn't work and I'd be glad to get some helpful information!

Comment: `[a for a in dir if "UPB" in a]` or `[a for a in dir if "UPB" not in a]`

Comment: "This should give me all the list elements from 'dir' which contain the string "UPB", right?" No. this will give you all the elements that  are **not** explicitly `'UPB'`.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thanks! That's exactly the right expression. Very handy!